# Adding Multiple values to Cakephp3 Configure::write

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to do something like php's *array_push*

I'm using Cakephp3 [Configure Class](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html) and want to store a list of user ids that are notified. Like this:

```
Configure::write('Notified_Users', 1);
Configure::write('Notified_Users', 2);
```

But the value 2 overrides value 1. 
Is there any way i can push data to this variable? and then later i can check if the selected user is in the list.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an array also this way

```
Configure::write('Notified_Users.0', 1);
Configure::write('Notified_Users.1', 2);
```

or simply

```
Configure::write('Notified_Users', [1, 2]);
```

if you `debug(Configure::read('Notified_Users'));` you'll get

```
[
    (int) 0 => (int) 1,
    (int) 1 => (int) 2
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Push data to this variable:

```
$notified_users = [];
array_push($notified_users,1);
Configure::write('Notified_Users', $notified_users);
```

Check if the selected user is in the list:

```
if (in_array(1, Configure::read('Notified_Users')))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Configure::write('Notified_Users', [1, 2, 3]);
```

or

```
Configure::write('Notified_Users', 
        [
            '0' => 1,
            '1' => 2,
            '2' => 3
        ]
    );
```